# eigen create super/sub diagonal matrix

Tags: c++, eigen

How would one create a matrix with elements along any specified diagonal without looping?

A toy example would be specifying a 3x3 matrix of ones and setting the indices to -1,0,1 and getting a full matrix that looked like:

```
 1     1     0
 1     1     1
 0     1     1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`diagonal`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1Diagonal.html) method accepts an index (zero is the default and indicates the main diagonal). Negative indices are subdiagonals, positive are superdiagonals. For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Core>

using namespace Eigen;

int main()
{
    MatrixXd mat(3,3);

    mat.setZero();

    for (auto i : { -1, 0, 1 })
        mat.diagonal(i).setConstant(1);

    std::cout << mat << "\n\n";
    return 0;
}
```

outputs the matrix you asked about.